# Typescript subclass accepted as value of superclass-type, but not as a parameter of a function that accepts a superclass-type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop

```
class Parent {
  str = 'a';
}
class ParentExtended extends Parent {
  num = 1;
}
class MyClass {
  static property?: Parent
  static method (p: Parent): void {}
  static func?: (pParam: Parent) => void
}
const pe: ParentExtended = {
  str: '',
  num: 1
}
// OK
MyClass.property = pe
// OK
MyClass.method(pe)
// Error
MyClass.func = (p: ParentExtended) => {}
```

```
Type '(p: ParentExtended) => void' is not assignable to type '(p: Parent) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'p' and 'pParam' are incompatible.
    Property 'num' is missing in type 'Parent' but required in type 'ParentExtended'.ts(2322)
```

Here, my extended class is accepted as a static field and as an argument to a method.

But when I assign `MyClass.func` (whose argument type is the child `ParentExtended`) a function whose argument type is `Parent`, TS says the parameters are incompatible. Why does this happen? How would I allow it to accept a function that accepts the child class (preferably without generics)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the [difference between covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign the function `func` declared as `(pParam: Parent) => void` a function which would be declared as `(p: ParentExtended) => void`.
Since `ParentExtended` is no super class of `Parent` its not working.
You cant ensure that every object inheriting the `Parent` behaviour also inherits the `ParentExtended` class.
Simple example:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

function test(obj: A) {}
```

In function `test` you could pass objects of type `B`, `C`.

Comment: But why would we care about any behavior outside of Parent if the only methods/fields we're ever going to use are in Parent within `func`? By that reasoning, shouldn't `ParentExtended` be accepted since only `Parent` methods/fields are used? (by the way, the code snippet is reproducing my `method` call which I understand, but is not identical to the case that I'm asking about which is a variable with a function value)

Comment: @platizin "*By that reasoning, shouldn't `ParentExtended` be accepted since only `Parent` methods/fields are used?*" - no. If you are only using `Parent` fields/methods, then you should also declare you parameter to have type `Parent`. (Which still makes the function accept `ParentExtended` values *as well*, but doesn't *require* them).

Comment: The method of the function itself will not change, regardless it its held in a variable or declared as a function statement. No since `ParentExtended` in a total other class, with for example another prototype. It just inherits the behaviour from the parent. Thats also why `(new Parent()) instanceof ParentExtended` will evaluate to false

Comment: Okay I think I understand it now - to put it in my own words, `MyClass.func` is expecting a function that only operates with `Parent` methods/fields, but the function passed is a function that accepts `ParentExtended`, which means it is potentially calling  methods/fields outside of `Parent`. Thanks guys